# Selenium Node will register to the grid, but not run any tests?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-grid

I am running a Selenium GRID on one of my corporate VM's and a Node on another.  When I launch my Node, it registers to the GRID (both the Node and the GRID confirm this), but then when I run my tests, I get the following error:

> org.openqa.selenium.remote.UnreachableBrowserException: Could not start a new > session. Possible causes are invalid address of the remote server or browser > start-up failure.

If I fire up a node on the same VM with the GRID, and register it using localhost, then the tests run fine.  I tried opening ports 4444 (GRID), and 5566 (Node) on both machines in windows firewall, but still no luck.  Is it just my companies network policy?  Is there something else I can try?  Thanks!

Here is what I am using to launch my GRID:

> java -jar "selenium-server-standalone-2.48.2.jar" -role hub -maxSession 10

Here is what I am using to launch my Node:

> java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.48.2.jar -role webdriver -Dwebdriver.ie.driver="C:\SeleniumDrivers\IEDriverServer.exe" -hub http://XX.XX.XX.XX:4444/grid/register -port 5566 -browser browserName="internet explorer",version=9.0,maxInstances=1,platform=WINDOWS -browser browserName="internet explorer",version=10.0,maxInstances=1,platform=WINDOWS -browser browserName="internet explorer",version=11.0,maxInstances=1,platform=WINDOWS -maxSession 1

Comment: Have you searched stackoverflow for your "org.openqa...." error message? There are a lot of hits.  See if any of them answer your question. If not, leave a comment here saying so.

Comment: For internet explorer, you'll need the IEServerDriver running and configured.  See https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=44069 for IE 11, for older versions of IE, see https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/InternetExplorerDriver

Comment: Mike.  After looking through most of them, they all ask you to make sure the webdriver System property is set. In other words, make sure your code has the path to the "IEDriverServer.exe".  I have tried that.  I even ran both the hub and the node on my new VM, and it works.  It only doesn't work when the hub and nodes are on diff VM's.  I have tried it both ways (VM1=hub, VM2=node :: VM1=node, VM2=hub).  What's so strange is that no matter how I set it up, I get a "The node is registered to the hub and ready to use" message on the node, and the "Registered a node on xyz address" on the hub.

Comment: I was also getting the same exception. Probable cause .. check the port whether its enabled in the firewall or not. Try doing telnet on the same ip and port.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out this was an issue with my corporate firewall policy.  By accessing the firewall settings on each node, I was able to look at the list of active firewall rules/policies.  From there, I found a few instances of java on some unexpected ports, that said they were being blocked.  I allowed those, and bingo, it all started working.

Answer (score 2):

Agree with Travis's answer above.  Adding some more detail for my specific case in the hopes that it helps others save time...

**Problem:** Selenium node registers with hub, but never really communicates and grid console shows node as existing but always down after timeout.  Grid console also stalls while loading for a long time before showing the node as down.

**Cause:** Node firewall was the issue.

**Context:**

1. Hub = Selenium 3.141 running on Win Server 2008
2. Node = Selenium 3.141 running on Win10 node

**Symptoms:**

1. Node would get thru to "The node is registered to the hub and ready
   to use".
2. The node never really was talking both ways with the hub
3. Grid Console (http://yourHubIp:4444/grid/console) would always stall with loading (in browser) until timeout hit, then show node as "DefaultRemoteProxy unknown version" and "Failed to connect to node IP".  This is the same error as if you took down a running node (kill command window).

**Fix:** From the node machine,

- Click Windows Start
- Run control panel
- Run Windows Firewall (or Windows Defender Firewall)
- Click "Allow an app or feature thru…"
- Set "Java™ Platform SE binary" = checked for appropriate columns (domain, private, etc.).   If unchecked, then firewall wass blocking java traffic.

Comment: While setting up another hub, I realize the issue started because when I first ran Selenium as a hub an a give server, the Windows Firewall prompted me what to allow thru vs. not...I answered wrong and had to do the above steps to correct.  On the subsequent hub setup, I answered correctly at the first run Firewall prompt...did not have to make the adjustments above.